# Java - Stamp position coordinates inaccurate in iText

Tags: javascript, java, pdf, itext

I am making a web application using Javascript for the front end and this is how it works:

1. I start the application and it opens a web page via my browser.
2. It displays a PDF page obtained from my directory.
3. I have the option to click on a stamp and drag and move around the pdf and place where ever I want.
4. When I'm done, I could click Save and it automatically saves the pdf file in my directory.
5. I can open the pdf file in my folder to view the updated PDF along with the stamp added.

The problem is when I open the PDF file to view, the positioning is not identical to the positioning of the stamp in the web browser.

Here is a sample of the input (in web browser):
[image]

And here is a sample of the output in Adobe Reader ( which is not what I want) :
[image]

I am aware this is mainly because PDF is measured using **User Units** compared to Pixels in an image. There must be something I could change in **Rectangle** so it matches the position of the web page.
What would be the best way to find the right conversion so the position fits identically to where ever I save the stamp on?

Javascript:

```
function divMove(e){
        var div = document.getElementById('stamp');
        div.style.position = 'absolute';
        //div.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
        //div.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
        var box = div.getBoundingClientRect();
        mouse_top = e.clientY;
        mouse_left = e.clientX;
        var diff_x = mouse_left - box.left;
        var diff_y = mouse_top - box.top;
        div.style.top = ((Number(div.style.top.replace("px", "")) - 1) + diff_y) +"px";
        div.style.left = ((Number(div.style.left.replace("px", "")) - 1) + diff_x) +"px";
        document.getElementById("data").innerHTML =
            "mouse_top:" + mouse_top + "<br>mouse_left:" + mouse_left
    }

    function save(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "Save",
            data: {
                mouseTop : mouse_top,
                mouseLeft : mouse_left
            },
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (response) {
            //use response to set stamp
                if (response != null) {
                    var pdfAsArray = convertDataURIToBinary("data:application/pdf;base64, " + response);
                    loadPDFToViewer(pdfAsArray);
                    //document.getElementById("page-1").getElementsByClassName("pdfCanvas")[0].removeEventListener("click", addStamp);
                } else {
                    alert("Response is null");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Java (backend) :

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        //String src = "C:\\Apache Tomcat\\apache-tomcat-7.0.78\\myWork\\prototype\\haito.pdf";
        //String dest = "C:\\Apache Tomcat\\apache-tomcat-7.0.78\\myWork\\prototype\\test.pdf";

        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));

        String src = p.getProperty("src");
        String dest = p.getProperty("dest");
        String imgSrc = p.getProperty("stamp");

        PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src), new PdfWriter(dest));

        ImageData image = ImageDataFactory.create(imgSrc);

        float w = image.getWidth();
        float h = image.getHeight();
        System.out.println("w: " + w + ", h: " + h);


        float mouseX = Float.valueOf(request.getParameter("mouseTop"));
        float mouseY = Float.valueOf(request.getParameter("mouseLeft"));
        System.out.println("top: " + mouseX + ", left: " + mouseY);
        //  adjusted mouse X and mouse Y position
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(mouseX ,mouseY,w,h);
        PdfStampAnnotation stamp = new PdfStampAnnotation(rect).setStampName(new PdfName("Approved"));
        PdfFormXObject xObj = new PdfFormXObject(new Rectangle(w,h));
        PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(xObj,doc);
        canvas.addImage(image,0,0,false);
        //canvas.getGraphicsState();
        stamp.setNormalAppearance(xObj.getPdfObject());
        stamp.setFlags(PdfAnnotation.PRINT);
        stamp.setFlags(PdfAnnotation.LOCKED);
        for(int i=1;i<=doc.getNumberOfPages();i++)
        {
            doc.getPage(i).addAnnotation(stamp);
        }
        //doc.getFirstPage().addAnnotation(stamp);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("config.properties");
        p.setProperty("src", dest);
        p.setProperty("dest", src);
        p.store(out, null);
        out.close();
        doc.close();

        ....................


    }
```

Comment: Please check how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest you provide some sample input (mouse Top, mouse left) and capture the wrong and expected result also. There is no need to concern the client side program, only server side function is enough.

Comment: Your post was rather long and I only looked at it briefly, but I saw that you know that there's a difference between pixels and user units. However, at first sight, I don't see you converting pixels into user units anywhere. Would this post be helpful to answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50616145

Comment: @samabcde I edited my post with some sample input and output

Comment: Can you also add the numeric value of mouse top, left from client side, original position of the stamp, and the updated position of the stamp?

Comment: @samabcde I can't locate the position of the stamp in the PDF though if that's what you're asking

Comment: @BrunoLowagie So the only way to avoid this positioning problem is through conversion?

Comment: *"So the only way to avoid this positioning problem is through conversion?"* - Well, yes, if two different coordinate systems are used, one has to transform the coordinates. That being said I see you using the *top* left corner as anchor point; in PDF it's usually the *bottom* left corner. Furthermore, your images look like there probably also is page rotation to consider.